# Writing multiple objects of different classes in the same file

Tags: java

Is it possible to write multiple objects of different classes in the same file using serialization if so how will i be able read different objects from the same file

```
FileOutputStream file=new FileOutputStream("G:\\File.txt");
        FileInputStream fileread=new FileInputStream("G:\\File.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream write=new ObjectOutputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream read=new ObjectInputStream(fileread);
        
        Teacher tc=new Teacher();
       Teacher tc2=new Teacher();
        tc.name="Ahmad";
        tc.age=21;
        tc2.name="Bilal";
        tc2.age=19;
        Student std=new Student();
        std.name="Ahmad";
        std.age=21;
        try{
            
        
        write.writeObject(tc);
                write.writeObject(tc2);
                write.writeObject(std);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
          
        } 
Teacher tc3=(Teacher)read.readObject();
           Student std4=(Student)read.readObject();
```

This is what i have been trying to do

Comment: You have to read exactly what you write.  You wrote two Teacher instances and one Student instance.  You have to read two Teacher instances and one Student instance.  You have to flush and close your output stream and reopen it as an input stream,

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to write multiple objects of different classes in the same file using serialization

Yes it is possible.

> ... if so how will i be able read different objects from the same file

You read them using `readObject` in the same order that you wrote them with `writeObject`.

---

It looks like the problem with your attempt is that that you write two `Teacher` objects followed by a `Student` object ... but you read **one** `Teacher` objects followed by a `Student` object.  So you will get a class cast exception because you are attempting to task a `Student` to a `Teacher`.

Another possible flaw in your code is that you may not be writing the object stream header soon enough.

The problem is that when you construct an `ObjectInputStream` it will *eagerly* attempt to read the object stream header from the stream that you wrapped.  The `ObjectOutputStream` constructor will write the head, but until something flushes (or closes) the `ObjectOutputStream`, the header may not be written its wrapped output stream.  If the attempt to read the header happens before it is actually written, the `ObjectInputStream` constructor will thrown an exception saying that the object stream is corrupt.

Indeed, you always have to be careful about this kind of thing when you application is simultaneously trying to read and write the same file.  My advice would be to avoid doing that.